# Copy date and time of KDE calender in text format to clipboard

Tags: 13.10, kde

Is there a way to set a shortcut-key for copying a text format of current date and time of KDE environment's calender?

Comment: You want a keyboard shortcut that copies the current date and time to the clipboard?

Comment: yep‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you intend to use KDE Calendar for such a simple task? Why not to define a global shortcut

```
System Setting › Shortcuts and Gestures › Custom Shortcuts › Edit › New › Global Shortcut › Command / URL
```

for

```
date | xsel -i -b
```

?

You may use any imaginable date format if default (`Fri Dec 20 09:33:37 MSK 2013`)
 does not suite you, see `date(1)`. E. g. `date '+%F %T'` will generate lexicographically sortable `2013-12-20 09:33:59`.

Instead of `xsel -i -b` you also can use `xclip -i -selection clipboard`.

I assume you want to copy to `CLIPBOARD`. Use just `xsel -i` or `xclip -i` if you want to put date to `PRIMARY` selection.

Comment: `date(1)` is reference to the man page. Use `$ man date` command or man:/date(1) URL in Konqueror.

Comment: I want KDE Calender because it has a local calender. btw, thanks this can be helpful and even more if you add a command for an immediate paste after copy.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Dmitry Alexandrov](https://askubuntu.com/users/224918/dmitry-alexandrov)'s answer above and [wilf](https://askubuntu.com/a/393645/126106)'s answer, one can also set this command (as in answer above):

```
date '+%A, %Y/%m/%d  %H:%M:%S' | xsel -i -b && xdotool type '  ' && xdotool key ctrl+v BackSpace && xdotool type '  '
```

which will copy and then immediately paste a format of date and time. Hotkey 'F8' seems to be appropriate and works for me:
  `Saturday, 2013/12/21  02:00:27` (other hotkeys may interfere with `xdotool`).

Copying KDE date and time format is unsolved yet.