# A command for KDE short date format

Tags: kubuntu, kde, calendar, date

By the command

```
$date
```

the time and date of the system (according to local place) is printed. Is there a command that outputs Kde's *short date format* in terminal?

[image]

---

The date in KDE also depends on a calender:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `date` for that anyway:

```
date '+%A, %Y/%m/%d'
```

which will currently output

```
Friday, 2013/12/20
```

Just run `date --help` to find out more...[image: smiley]

---

For calendar specific, or at least locale specific, specific date names, try exporting the locale - e.g. this one:

```
export LC_TIME=am_ET.UTF-8
```

and then run the command again:

```
ዓርብ, 2013/12/20
```

You can list the locales with `locale -a` - more on that [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E26033/glmha.html).

<sub>This bit is based on a lot of guessing...</sub>

Comment: useful. But KDE has a calendar type parameter.

Comment: Does the above do what you want?

Comment: thanks. But still I don't think a non-kde command can produce the date and time as shown in the second image above.

Comment: KDE would not have its own commands, it would have it as a feature within their programs... As such, there is not likely to be a command for it... :-s