# Copy a date from the calender in top bar

Tags: clipboard, calendar

I have already seen [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376736/copy-date-and-time-of-kde-calender-in-text-format-to-clipboard). However, this allows you to copy (and paste) only the current date.

Let us say that you have displayed the calender in your top bar.

[image]

Then you select a particular date (*not* the current date) by clicking on it.

How do I copy the selected date so that it can be subsequently pasted?

*(If the above can not be done, is there a particular tool or chain of
commands which can be used for the purpose?)*

Comment: Excellent question, badly in need of a good answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by following these steps:

1. Open system settings
2. Go to Time & Date
3. At the bottom, select to set time manually, instead of automatically
4. Change the time and date to the time and date that you want to copy
5. Exit the window
6. Follow [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376736/copy-date-and-time-of-kde-calender-in-text-format-to-clipboard) instructions to copy date

Comment: Is not that a bit *too much* to copy a date? How is that better than simply keying-in the date?

Comment: You're right, sorry.